# How to make internal mapping class for NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I made internal classes for my mappings and put everywhere "default-lazy=false".
After a while I decided to go with full lazy and removed this setting. Suddenly almost everything fails to execute. Exception I'm getting is "Cannot execute query... System.TypeLoadException: Access is denied to...".
 This of course is because of the fact that classes are marked as internal and therefore they cannot be accessed by nhibernate.dll. That's why I also added to AssemblyInfo.cs lines:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo(InternalsVisible.ToDynamicProxyGenAssembly2)]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo(InternalsVisible.ToCastleCore)]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyUnitTestsDLL")]
```

But it doesn't help. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try adding:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("NHibernate")]
```

If this doesn't work, look at the stack trace of the TypeLoadException and check to see what DDL the exception is being thrown from- add a InternalsVisibleTo attribute for it.

My guess is that the NHibernate DDL is trying to do something a bit more clever now lazy loading is enabled.. perhaps it has to have access to the internal class for some reason or another (vague but I don't know the source code of NHibernate)

EDIT:

try adding:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("mscorlib")]
```

You have have to specify the public key/version of the assembly you are using.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not it. Any other ideas?

Comment: Could you copy/paste the full stack trace of the TypeLoadException? That may shed some light.

Comment: Added a new edit for you. Additionally, what are the values of the variables "InternalsVisible.ToDynamicProxyGenAssembly2" and "InternalsVisible.ToCastleCore"?

Comment: Thanks for help, but in the end I went with "public". Seems too much to handle simple situation.

Comment: A Wise choice :) No need to needlessly make things complex

Comment: This is not really an answer for the question but it is marked as an answer. IMHO This is not a wise choice really - when you need your DAL Entities to be internal as you make only the DTOs public. you don't want any work to be against an NH entity...

Comment: Real answer is here using T4 template to change the AssemblyInfo.cs on build - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151730/nhibernate-mapped-internal-classes-and-internalsvisibleto