# Nhibernate mapped internal classes and InternalsVisibleTo

Tags: c#, nhibernate

My proxy generator is having trouble generating proxies for internal mapped Nhibernate classes. I have tried adding them as visible using InternalsVisibleTo in assemblyinfo.cs but it doesn't seem to work. Worse, I don't know how to tell if I've even successfully managed to friend the proxy assemblies I want to because if I change a few numbers in the proxy assemblies public key in assemblyinfo.cs there is no error thrown.

Error:

Test method TestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw exception: 
NHibernate.HibernateException: Creating a proxy instance failed ---> Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.GeneratorException: Type is not public, so a proxy cannot be generated. Type: BaseSystemCore.Domain.Lot

StackTrace:

Castle.DynamicProxy.DefaultProxyBuilder.AssertValidType(Type target)
Castle.DynamicProxy.DefaultProxyBuilder.CreateClassProxy(Type classToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, ProxyGenerationOptions options)
Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxy(Type classToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, ProxyGenerationOptions options, Object[] constructorArguments, IInterceptor[] interceptors)
NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactory.GetProxy(Object id, ISessionImplementor session)
NHibernateUtilities.BaseUnitOfWork.handleException(Exception e) in C:\Users\Isaac.G\Desktop\svn.bolinger.ca\Library Projects\NHibernateUtilities\NHibernateUtilities\BaseUnitOfWork.cs: line 871
NHibernateUtilities.BaseUnitOfWork.getAllT in C:\Users\Isaac.G\Desktop\svn.bolinger.ca\Library Projects\NHibernateUtilities\NHibernateUtilities\BaseUnitOfWork.cs: line 115
TestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1() in C:\Users\Isaac.G\Desktop\svn.bolinger.ca\Library Projects\BaseSystemCore\TestProject1\UnitTest1.cs: line 71

Has anyone ever got this to work before?

Thanks

Isaac

Comment: possible duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028318/how-to-make-internal-mapping-class-for-nhibernate. Post exception message and stack trace if the answer to this question does not help.

Comment: in the end, that guy didn't get it to work :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NHibernate 3.2 has built in proxy provider. I briefly look at the sources at it seems like they use this format: {0}ProxyAssembly. Where {0} is a type name for lazy mapped class. I have not tested it though. Try adding following to your AssemblyInfo.cs and replace {0} with your lazy class name:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("{0}ProxyAssembly")]
```

If you still want to use older version of NHibernate you can try using this (for castle byte code provider):

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")]
```

DynamicProxyGenAssembly2 is a temporary assembly that gets generated on the fly by Castle. It contains classes derived from your mapped classes (proxies).

Comment: I don't understand where this DynamicProxyGenAssembly2 is. It's not a dll. Can there be assemblies inside of other assemblies?

Comment: This is a temporary assembly generated on the fly, similar to how .NET generates assemblies for xml serialization.

Comment: how would i get its public key?

Comment: ah, i see there's no need for that.

Comment: this works, thanks so much! I've been fiddling with this for hours, I did not understand that the actual assembly that was running was not the same one as the dll in the directory.

Comment: I have now switched to Nhibernate 3.2. InternalsVisibleTo("NHibernate")] Doesn't work!

Comment: It works, but now I have to find a way to auto internalsVisibleTo every class in my domain. I hope 3.2 lets me use Castle again if I get sick of this!

Comment: This approach also allows declare as internal all domain classes (= class of which instances can be persisted via NHibernate). Personally I prefer having domain classes internal to avoid accidental use outside of the assembly. This of course locks out the proxy assemblies that NHibernate generates on the fly, and results in having to add the InternalsVisibleTo() attributes. Note that I accept other people's preference to have those classes declared as public.

Answer (score 2):

For what its worth, this is what I've dropped into a T4. It automatically generates all the `InternalsVisibleTo` attributes for my entities. Hope it helps.

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)\Domain\bin\Debug\Domain.dll" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

<#
 var publicType = typeof(Domain.Foo);
 var allTypes = publicType.Assembly.GetTypes();

 var entityType = allTypes.Single(t => t.FullName == "Domain.Entities.Entity"); // my entity supertype

 foreach(var type in allTypes.Where(t => !t.IsAbstract && entityType.IsAssignableFrom(t)))
{#>
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("<#= type.Name #>ProxyAssembly")]
<#}#>
```